# Visual Studio Code "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, window, mingw

so I am trying to make a Windows Desktop Application with c++ in Visual Studio Code and using MinGW as my compiler.
I have a file called *test.cpp* in a folder called *src*:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 
#include <windows.h>

int wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR lpCmdLine, 
int nCmdShow){

  const wchar_t name[] = L"Test";

  WNDCLASS wc = {};
  //wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.lpszClassName = name;

  RegisterClass(&wc);

  HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0, 
    name, 
    L"Window", 
    WS_BORDER, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    1200, 
    720, 
    0, 
    0, 
    hInstance, 
    0);

  if(hWnd == NULL){
    return 0;
  }

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
}
```

But when I compile I get this error:

```
> Executing task: g++ -g test.cpp -o test.exe <

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I also have a *tasks.json* and a *launch.json* in *.vscode folder*:

**tasks.json**

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "test",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "g++",
    "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    },
    "args": [
      "-g", "test.cpp", "-o", "test.exe"
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]
```

**Launch.json**

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  {
    "name": "(Windows) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/test.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "preLaunchTask": "test"
  }
]
```

The problem is that when I build a file with a *main* function it compiles fine, but when it is done with *wWinMain* that error happens and I don't know how to fix it. I'll really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 24):

I had the similar question, save the file manually and compile it again.

Comment: You're a genius! I was just assuming that it was auto-saving like PyCharm does.

Comment: can u tell me Please In my vs code errors not highlighted by red lines..(Earlier they are highlighted)

Answer (score 6):

Just include a `main()` function in your code and you will be good to go.
It's just that your program doesn't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code runner setting “save file before run”.

Answer (score 1):

WinMain@16 usually appears when you try to compile some files, which don't contain the `main()/WinMain()` function (starting point of the program). In your case, not including the source file with the `main()/WinMain()` function in it was causing your troubles.

Comment: Hi RistoS, so you ar esaying that I have to manually include the file where the WinMain function is included right? So in these case, that would be the window.h?

Comment: So what if you want to just build the one file out of your whole folder?