# I wrote a basic code and its not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

> PS D:\vs> cd "d:\vs" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\tempCodeRunnerFile }
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I wrote this code. I am using Visual Studio Code. I have installed extensions like C/C++ and Code Runner. I have correctly installed mingw.
I have also added environment variables of `mingw/bin` . It is continuously showing this error message, and I have tried everything.

Comment: Did you try opening the vs code as Administrator?

Comment: You are person 1234567 who is asking this same question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code "undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092183/visual-studio-code-undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092183/visual-studio-code-undefined-reference-to-winmain16), basically this error comes when the compiler doesn't recognize a main function, but it seems like you do have one, so try manually saving before compiling.

Comment: That worked a new .exe file is created but now my antivirus automatically deleted that .exe file and showing trojan found........when i stop my antivirus it is working.......but that trojan might affect my computer

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you either don't save before running or you are just selecting the piece of code and trying to run it. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout <<"hello world";
    return 0;
// you have to press ctrl+shift+b then search box open choose g++.exe to build task then type g++ .\4.cpp then run .\4.exe ur code is run . otherwise u r not install prooperly compilee.
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).